# one-sided one-sided 95% confidence bound based on comparitive percentile difference between column values

Tags: r, confidence-interval

If I had a data set as follows, how would I find the percentage of measurements in columns A and B that falls within +/-15% of its corresponding value in C and then find the lower one-sided 95% confidence bound value in %.

1. Instead of manually finding if the values in each row of columns A or B is within 15% of C, is there a better way (a predefined function in R) to calculate this for very large data sets?
2. How do I find the one-sided lower confidence bound value in % for cols A and B?

my code so far for finding out which all readings (row values) fall within +/-15% of column C.

```
library(data.table)
dataDF <- data.frame(
  a = c(96,94,92,85,83,79,75,71,74,79,81,87,89,98,105,NA, 168,173,164,155,145,134,129,126,120,108,100,95,98,105,113,112,113,110,106,105,100,100,95,95,94),
  b = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 45, 48, 52, 57, 56, 56, NA, NA, 135,181,130,128,121,119,147,117,112,104,100,105,130,126,127,131,129,125,124,119,119,113,109,109),
  c = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,148,151,163.5,175,171.5,206.5,207.5,214,227,NA,NA,183.5,169,NA,147,144.5,137,118.5,104.5,128.5, 132,155.5,171.5,165.5,NA,145.5,NA,130,105,120.5,124.5,136,129.5))
# remove NA rows
df <- dataDF[complete.cases(dataDF),]

# create a func to find number of readings within % of control
pct_fun <- function(vec, ctrl, pct)
          {
            # check
            n = length(vec)
            ## initialize to FALSE
            res = rep(FALSE, n)
            # do the math
            for(i in 1:n)
              if(any(abs(vec[i]-ctrl[i])<=ctrl[i]*pct, na.rm = TRUE))
                res[i] = TRUE
            # throw result
            res
          }
setDT(df)
df[, pct_col := pct_fun(a, c, .15)]

# calculate the percentage of TRUE/FALSE
pct_res <- sum(df$pct_col)/length(df$pct_col)
print(pct_res*100.00)
```